# SyntaxError: missing : after property id with Google Maps Javascript API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-api

I'm using the Google Maps Javascript API and this line is giving me error "SyntaxError: missing : after property id":

```
var options = {
     zoom: 4.5,
     center: { lat: 59.65, lng: -130.00 }
}
```

and this also occurs when I call the AddMarker function:

```
addMarker({
     coords: { lat: 58,74168, lng: -123,24657 }
});
```

I can't wrap my head around why this syntax is incorrect.

EDIT:
I've set my regional settings to French so the dots in my lat and long have been replaced with commas. However, the API expects dots, so how would I get around this?

Comment: ^ second object uses commas where there should be periods.

Comment: You're probably passign this to a method that needs an id property. What happens if you include id as property with a generic value ?

Comment: You have the properties `74168` & `24657` without a colon. I know that's not what those values are supposed to be, but it won't allow commas or it separates them into new properties.

Comment: In the second object that's probably a regional setting. comma is used as a decimal separator in many countries. But it probably expects the dot to be used as a separator.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira Thank you! That's exactly what's happening. I'm setting my language to French. How would I tell the API to accept commas or perhaps force dots instead?

Comment: Created an answer. If it was useful please accept/upvote. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second object that's probably a regional setting. Comma is used as a decimal separator in many countries. But it probably expects the dot to be used as a separator.

Comment: I would like to keep my regional settings to be French. How would I get the Google Maps API to cooperate with commas?

Comment: That part I don't know :)